# How to display user input after prompt in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently coding a text based game in python in which the narrative will start differently depending on answers to certain questions. The first question is simple, a name. I can't seem to get the input to display in the correct text option after the prompt.

I tried using

"if name is True"

and

"if name is str"

but they both skip to the else option, instead of displaying the correct option after input.

```
while True:
    try:
        # This will query for first user input, Name.

        name = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")

        # No valid input will restart loop.

        continue
    else:

        break

if name is str:
    print("Ah, so " + name + " is your name? Excellent.")
else:
    print("No name? That's fine, I suppose.")
```

So if I enter John as my name, I'd expect the output to be "Ah, so John is your name? Excellent."

But instead I enter John and it outputs:

Please enter your name: John

No name? That's fine, I suppose.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you think `if name is str:` is doing?

Comment: You do not need to check if `name is str` - `if name.strip():` will check if the input is different from whitespaces (i.e. You got some input thats visible) - if name is str checks if name is str not if name is a non-empty string instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `isinstance` instead of `is`.
And, You do not need to use `str(input())` because `input` returns `str`.

```
while True:
    try:
        # This will query for first user input, Name.
        name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        # No valid input will restart loop.
        continue
    else:
        break

if isinstance(name, str):
    print("Ah, so " + name + " is your name? Excellent.")
else:
    print("No name? That's fine, I suppose.")
```

The result is:

```
Please enter your name: John
Ah, so John is your name? Excellent.
```

But, You have to use `string.isalpha()` if you want to check whether `name` is real name in consist of alphabets.

```
if name.isalpha():
    print("Ah, so " + name + " is your name? Excellent.")
else:
    print("No name? That's fine, I suppose.")
```

Comment: While using `isinstance` is good, this still won't work as _name_ will always be a `str`

Comment: `input` always returns a `str` so the else branch of the if statement can never be reached.

Comment: @Tim You are right. But, I think OP just wants to know why `is` is not working.

Comment: @yahocho. OP seems to want to understand how to check for an empty string, an by extension, why the existing code doesn't work.

Comment: @MadPhysicist By the question of OP, `name` must be checked whether name could be real name or not if we must fully understand OP's intention. I updated my code for checking `name` with `isalpha()`.

Comment: @yahocho that isn't what the op asked, the question was how do I determine if a name is entered and present the two outcomes. Which is not what your entry here does, you have invented a new requirement. Along with exception handling that essentially does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

The exception handling around `input` is not required as the `input` function always returns a string. If the user does not enter a value an empty string is returned.

Therefore your code can be simplified to

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")

# In python an empty string is considered `False` allowing 
# you to use an if statement like this.
if name:
    print("Ah, so " + name + " is your name? Excellent.")
else:
    print("No name? That's fine, I suppose.")
```

Further regarding usage of `is`:

`is` is used to compare identity as in two variables refer to the same object. It's more common use is to test if a variable is `None` eg `if name is None` (`None` is always the same object). As mentioned you can use `type(name)` to obtain the type of variable *name* but this is discouraged in place of the builtin check `isinstance`.

`==` on the other hand compares equality as in `if name == "Dave"`.

`isinstance` does more than just check for a specific type, it also handles inherited types.

Comment: `is` compares identities not types

Comment: @Tim By the question of OP, `name` must be checked whether name could be real name or not if we consider OP's intention.

Comment: @yaho Cho `input()` does not generate `ValueError`. It accepts any string (including an empty string). The code I have listed does exactly what the op asked without the extra code that doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is you're checking if name is str, not if type(name) is str.

```
  if type(name) is str:
```

Comment: This approach is discouraged, you should use `isinstance(name, str)`.